# Is there an easy way to eliminate duplicate rows in a DataFrame in Python- pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My problem is that my data isn't a good representation of what is really going on because it has a lot of duplicate rows. Consider the following-

```
    a    b
1  23   42
2  23   42
3  23   42
4  14   12
5  14   12
```

I only want 1 row and to eliminate all duplicates. It should look like the following after it's done.

```
    a    b
1  23   42
2  14   12
```

Is there a function to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Let's use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates) with `keep='first'`:

```
df2.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

Output:

```
    a   b
1  23  42
4  14  12
```

Comment: Great answer and I'm sure it works... but `ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)`.

Comment: Can you print the head of your actual data?

Comment: I can't. It's a security risk.

Comment: Multiindex data?  See if you can recreate dummy data that reproduces this error.

Comment: @NickTheInventor df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['a','b']) You could try something like this if you don't want to conder all the columns.